Discrepancy between "df" and "du" on a CIFS network drive
When I run df -H, my network mount reports 100% usage:
user@system:/mnt/backup$ df -H
Filesystem                                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
//192.168.71.2/Linux-Database-Backup-Storage  806G  806G     0 100% /mnt/backup

Running stat -f confirms there are no free inodes/blocks:
user@system:/mnt/backup$ stat -f /mnt/backup
  File: "/mnt/backup"
    ID: 0        Namelen: 255     Type: smb2
Block size: 1024       Fundamental block size: 1024
Blocks: Total: 786432000  Free: 0          Available: 0
Inodes: Total: 0          Free: 0

However, when I try to find what's using up all the disk space, the reported usage (~115G)  isn't anywhere near the network mount size (~806G):
user@system:/mnt/backup$ du -h /mnt/backup
13G     /mnt/backup/backups-a
99G     /mnt/backup/backups-b
3.7G    /mnt/backup/backups-c
115G    /mnt/backup

I have a relatively small number of files as well, checking the reported inodes usage only reports 66 inodes in use:
user@system:/mnt/backup$ du -s --inodes /mnt/backup | sort -rn
66      /mnt/backup

My /etc/fstab configuration:
user@system:/mnt/backup$ cat /etc/fstab
\\192.168.71.2\Linux-Database-Backup-Storage       /mnt/backup     cifs    credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials2,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,vers=2.0,_netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000   0       0

Why is there a discrepancy between df and du? What's using up all the extra storage?
Thanks!

There are various possible reasons for this, mostly hinging around the fact that a network share need not correspond to an entire filesystem. Here, it's possible that although the remote filesystem is 806GB, only part of it is being exported to you over the network. You have used 115GB but another party has used the remaining 690GB or so.
Here's an illustrative example from my home network:
mkdir -p /mnt/net
mount -o 'user=…' //REMOTE/Share /mnt/net

df -h /mnt/net
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
//REMOTE/Share   984G  915G   59G  94% /mnt/net

du -hsx /mnt/net
8.7G    /mnt/net

In my situation there is a 1TB filesystem that is shared out in a number of different ways. (Each of my family members has their own semi-private network share, for example.) The total usage is 915GB of 984GB but the share shown here is using less than 10GB of it.

Turns out the network user for the CIFS store had a quota set, not the folders themselves. Just disabling this quota fixed it.
